# Spring Security, OpenID, and mod_proxy

Tags: spring-security, openid, mod-proxy

I have an application using spring-security's OpenID implementation. The app server sits behind a proxy. The proxy is apache httpd with mod_proxy. If the proxy connects to the app server via HTTP, the  application will tell the OpenID authenticator to redirect back via HTTP rather than HTTPS like I would prefer. It seems to pull the protocol dynamically and only sees HTTP. If I configure the proxy to use HTTPS, I run into [this problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/496888/ssl-issue-with-mod-proxy?noredirect=1#comment557272_496888). So is there a way to operate spring security behind a proxy which uses HTTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little extra mod_proxy and Glassfish configuration solved this problem for me:

https://serverfault.com/questions/496888/ssl-issue-with-mod-proxy